# SAPUI5 List sorting issue

Tags: sapui5

I would like to sort my list items by date. But I when I applied the sorter to my list there is no changes on the list. My code is below. Where I am doing mistake ? Please let me know about this problem.
Thanks a lot.

```
new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                      type: "Active",
                      title: "Sort by date",
                      press:function(oEvent){
                        var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("CRDT",false,false);
                        var oList = _this.getView().byId("commentListView");
                        var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
                        oSorter.fnCompare = function(firstParam,secondParam) {
                            var firstDate = Date.parse(firstParam).getTime();
                            var secondDate = Date.parse(secondParam).getTime();
                            return firstDate === secondDate ? 0 : (firstDate < secondDate ? -1 : 1);
                        };
                        oBinding.sort(oSorter);
                      }
                    }).addStyleClass("sapUiNoMargin sapUiNoContentPadding"),
```

Comment: firstParam and secondParam variables contain date string (For example: 18 May 2018). So I need to convert this string variable to Date type.

Comment: I've solved this issue by using this type of sorter =>  var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter({
                              path:"CRDT",
                              descending:false,
                              group:false
                            });